# Twitter API oAUTH

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, social-networking

I have implemented twitter API (oAUTH) by going through this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/ . Its working and I can update my status (which I am guessing its kinda sharing) . The problem I am facing now is how can I add pictures , few words and a link to this `$twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Hello Nettuts+'));`. Something like twitter cards.

Is there another good tutorial which explains and demonstarte all the functions of Twitter API (oAUTH).

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can include a link/URL in your status update in the same way that you have included the other words (Hello Nettuts+).

However, you cannot add pictures in this manner - you will need to use the `statuses/update_with_media` endpoint as opposed to the `statuses/update` endpoint that you are using in your existing code. You can learn more about how to do this by reading Twitter's API documentation:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

And you can see some example code here:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059